# Как напечатать числа от 1 до 100? Python

Tags: python, for, range, перебор

Иногда люди задают такой вопрос:

> А как мне вывести все числа от 1 до 100 через пробел с помощью цикла `for` и `print`?

Как его осуществить в реальность? Спасибо заранее

Comment: Сокращаем много вопросов в один)

Comment: перебрать или отобразить - это разные вещи :)

Comment: кстати если задача из серии - не использовать `range` - приходится подумать, если еще не использовать `enumerate` то еще больше думать приходится, а если еще и в 1 строчку записать, то в голову пока что-то ничего не проходит (не считая задать строку заранее в явном виде, но это не считается)

Comment: Числа натуральные или в принципе любые?

Comment: до 100 включительно?

Comment: Натуральные. Включительно

Comment: За что дизлайки?

Comment: Мы же ruSO лучше делаем, от "загрязнений из одинаковых вопросов" очищаем

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТверсия-3-8 не волнуйся это просто партия "закрывашек"снова бушует ,  я тебя плюсанул :3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Решение в лоб без генераторов:

```
i = 1
while i < 102:
    print(i, end=' ')
    i += 1
```

Но стандартные примеры не очень интересны, попробуем жесть и экзотику.

Так:

```
[print(i[0], end=' ') for i in enumerate(' ' * 100, 1)]
```

или:

```
[print(i, end=' ') for i, j in enumerate(' ' * 100, 1)]
```

или:

```
print(*[i for i, j in enumerate(' ' * 100, 1)])
```

Comment: Экзотично 8) А что делает `enumerate` ?

Comment: каждому элементу множества ставит в соответствие порядковый номер :) начиная с заданного (по умолчанию с 0, но я выставил чтобы с 1)

Comment: А, понятно, спасибо

Answer (score 3):

дополню "библиотеку":

вариация на тему цикла (для `python 3.8` и старше):

```
c = 0
while (c:= c+1)<=100: print(c)
```

и бессмысленная и беспощадная рекурсия :)

```
f = lambda x=0: print(x) if x<=1 else f(x-1) or print(x)
f(100)
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое)

Comment: Спасибо ещё раз за такие интересные варианты)

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТверсия3-8, пожалуйста. Иногда даже простые задачки могут быть интересными.

Answer (score 1):

### Есть много способов, я покажу только 3.

**1.**  Самый простой перебор через `for`.

```
for i in range(1, 101):
    print(i, end=' ')
```

Его можно записать короче, просто совместив 2 строки:

```
for i in range(1, 101): print(i, end=' ')
```

Или записать так (спасибо @Zhihar ):

```
[print(i, end=' ') for i in range(1, 101)]
```

**2.** Перебор тоже через `for`. В этом случае мы печатаем список из элементов от 1 до 100.

```
print(' '.join(str(i) for i in range(1, 101)])
```

Ещё один вариант от @Zhihar :

```
print(' '.join(map(str, range(1, 101))))
```

**3.** Самый короткий способ с `range`.

```
print(*range(1, 101))
```

Comment: Если кто-то знает ещё, можете дополнить мою умственную"библиотеку" =)

Comment: вместо `for i in range(1, 101): print(i, end=' ')` можно и так `[print(i, end=' ') for i in range(1, 101)]`

Comment: в 3 способе ошиблись - до 101 надо как и выше

Comment: в `join` можно убрать `[]` - `print(' '.join(str(i) for i in range(1, 101)))`

Comment: к 'join' ловите более короткий аналог - `print(' '.join(map(str, range(1, 101))))`